# Посоветуйте сервер для Android-приложения

Tags: android, сервер

Собираюсь писать android-приложение. В котором буду использовать сервер. Почитал в интернете про различные сервера, ну так и не пришел к выводу что лучше и на чем писать (смотрел в сторону `JSON-сервера`)
Посоветуйте сервер, логика приложения в том что у каждого пользователя есть свой id. По отобранным критериям он будет получать данные с сервера, и может ставить рейтинг полученным данным(статье), и оценка идет на сервер.
Какой вы могли бы порекомендовать для данного функционала?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно "сервер" пишут самостоятельно на удобном для разработчика языке. Так как ваше android-приложение с высокой степенью вероятности написано на Java, то и серверный функционал можно написать на Java. Пишите логику на [Servlet API](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82_(Java)) или [Spring MVC](https://spring.io/) и разворачиваете в каком-нибудь web-контейнере, типа [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) или [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/). Но если вам нужен способ получать из БД данные в формате JSON с минимальными телодвижениями, то посмотрите на [PostgREST](https://github.com/begriffs/postgrest).

Answer (score 0):

Если писать свой сервер нет желания/времени/знаний то можно использовать какой нибудь SaaS сервис. Например, Google предлагает [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start), который достаточно просто интегрируется в Android приложение (также есть поддержка iOS). Он предоставляет много фишек сразу из коробки, например, реалтайм синхронизацию данных на сервере и устройстве.

Конечно, функционал его ограничен и его не расширить по своему желанию, как это можно сделать с самописным сервером, но под описанную в вопросе задачу он вполне подойдёт.